# It fits on every person

Tags: riddle, word

Clue 1:

> All starts and all finishes

Clue 2:

> Good or bad

Clue 3:

> Every person is affected by _______s

Clue 4:

> Used as a linking verb, too

Clue 5:

> As many letters as a brand acquired by David Razon in 2012

**Who am I?**

Comment: Sorry the last clue is misleading

Comment: @Deepthinker101 Not a problem, I just clarified it now :)

Comment: That is not the problem it was the fact you said that it has the same amount of letters when you are looking for the exact name correlation.

Comment: What am I supposed to do?

Comment: @Jingbothedude, the answer should just find a word that matches all the clues, it's a just a riddle

Answer (score 1):

I guess the solution could be

> feeling

It fits on every person

> I cannot really distinguish this from clue 3. Maybe a play with multiple meanings of fit? Although not every person is prone to having fits.

All starts and all finishes

> I don't really see a connection here. Maybe The Jackson 5 song 'It all begins and ends with love'? Certainly a strong feeling.

Good or bad

> you might argue that there are no neutral feelings; that it's not a feeling if it leaves you emotionally unaffected. So any feeling would have to be good or bad.

Every person is affected by _______s

> Sure. The argument is same as above: If it doesn't affect me, I don't feel it.

Used as a linking verb, too

> To feel is a very common and typical linking verb.

As many letters as a brand acquired by David Razon in 2012

> I assume this ambiguous clue relates to the company seven7, and you hint at seven letters, not 5 (or 6 if you count a digit as a letter).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a

> Tie?

It fits on every person

> A tie fits on every person because its length makes it very adjustable.

All starts and all finishes

> In order to have a tie in competitions, the players must've all started and finished.

Good or bad

> Winning is good, losing is bad, and a tie is good or bad.

Every person is affected by _______s

> I guess people get frustrated when they have trouble tying a tie?

Used as a linking verb, too

> Tie can also be a verb. When you tie something, you are linking objects.

As many letters as a brand acquired by David Razon in 2012

> Not sure :)

Comment: Despite the good efforts, last clue is missing and unfortunately it's not the answer, I'm sorry :/